# Toolbar menu is closed when updates are made to UI in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I've noticed a problem with the toolbar menu closing when updates are made to the UI. I made a test project to verify this is the case, and the code is shown below. Here are the steps to reproduce the issue.

1. Open the menu
2. Wait 5s before an update is made to the UI (in this case the name)
3. The menu will automatically close

I found this problem is directly caused by the button action code: `selection = String(describing: View2.self)`. Here are the test cases I tried to find this out.

1. If I comment the `selection` code, then the problem doesn't exist.
2. To test that it isn't because it's linked to the NavigationLink, I commented the NavigationLink and uncommented the `selection` code, but the problem still exists.
3. If I replace the `selection` code with a simple print statement, then the problem doesn't exist.

I'm using Xcode 12.5.1. Tested on iOS 14.

How can I fix this problem?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var name = "John"
    @State var selection: String?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: View2(), tag: String(describing: View2.self), selection: $selection){}
                
                Text("Hello \(name)")
                    .padding()
            }
            .toolbar {
                Menu {
                    Button {
                        selection = String(describing: View2.self)
                    } label: {
                        Text("Edit")
                    }
                    
                    Button {
                        selection = String(describing: View2.self)
                    } label: {
                        Text("Help")
                    }
                } label: {
                    Text("Menu")
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
                    name = "Hunter"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Move updating part into separated sub-view, so it would not trigger rebuild of parent view completely.

Comment: BTW, not reproducible with Xcode13/iOS15